# Create service account in Gerrit that uses OAuth provided by Gitlab

Tags: authentication, jenkins, oauth, gitlab, gerrit

I have a Gerrit instance that was setup to authenticate users over LDAP. A second team came along and can only be authenticated over a second LDAP server. IT intends on keeping the two servers separate, and as far as I can tell it is not possible to authenticate against multiple LDAP servers in Gerrit.

We have a Gitlab server internally that is able to authenticate against both groups of users, possibly by magic. I have created an Application in Gitlab as an OAuth provider so that Gerrit can authenticate against it.

Everything appeared to work- everybody is able to login successfully. However, it is a bit annoying because with each login from Gerrit, the user needs to click "Authorize". What doesn't work, however, is that the Gerrit Trigger in Jenkins could no longer post the build results to Gerrit due to a 500 error.

My questions:
- What's the best way to solve this issue?
- Is there a way to support local accounts in Gerrit, when it is configured for OAuth?
- Is there a way to skip the "Authorize" page when logging in?

Please let me know if there are important details that I left out which can help with the answer.